# code for create database in android broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android

My objective is, i need to create a database using service class not in activity, for that i have created one service class which is given as follows.

```
   public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver
   {       
       @Override    
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
             select();//
        } 

        public void select()
        {
            SQLiteDatabase myDb;
            myDb = openOrCreateDatabase(path + "/" + db, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            cur4readdb = myDb.query("users",null, null, null, null, null, null);
            cur4readdb.moveToFirst();
            while (cur4readdb.isAfterLast() == false)
            {
               Log.i(TAG, " From SMSReceive : " + cur4readdb.getString(1));
               cur4readdb.moveToNext();
             }
            cur4readdb.close();
        }
    }
```

But, i got errors in this line :

```
    myDb = openOrCreateDatabase(path + "/" + db, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null); //openOrCreateDatabase is underlined in red colour.
```

In my main activity i have used the same code its working here. But not in service.
Will you anybody please tell me. is it possible or not. If yes means elaborate that solution.

```
    myDb = openOrCreateDatabase(path + "/" + db, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);       
    cur4readdb = myDb.query("users", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    cur4readdb.moveToFirst();
    while (cur4readdb.isAfterLast() == false)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "User : " + cur4readdb.getString(1));
        cur4readdb.moveToNext();            
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its a broadcast reciever not a service...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a compilation error.

`openOrCreateDatabase` can be seen in [`Context` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openOrCreateDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory%29). And both [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) extends the `Context` class.

You are not writing a service, but a receiver. BroadcastReceiver doesn't extend the Context class. You can use the context object in the receiver by `context.openOrCreateDatabase(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

`openOrCreateDatabase()` method is of Context class, so you need to call it from context object. i.e.

```
myDb = context.openOrCreateDatabase(path + "/" + db, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```